# Flutter build apk error: Could not determine java version from '11.0.15'

Tags: windows, flutter

```
* What went wrong:
Could not determine java version from '11.0.15'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                         1,390ms
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

i tried to build apk but got this error instead. i have installed newer version of java which is java 11 but still didnt work.

Comment: can you share the   distributionUrl  from the file. gradle-wrapper.properties from the android folder

Comment: @HardikMehta `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip`

Comment: Please change it to this distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
 and try once